# Promtail with Cloud Grafana Loki and winston JS log fields not detected

Tags: node.js, express, winston, grafana-loki, promtail

I have setup promtail (docker image) reading my .log files. Those logs are sent to Grafana Loki cloud.

I receive those logs succesfully but fields are not detected. Exemple of a log: `{"env":"development","file":"myFile","level":"info","message":"myMessage","service":"myApp"}`

Here it is what I can see in Loki:

[image]

As you can see, log is fully ingested but I do only have 2 fields (the labels) and the fields in my JSON log.
I don't know how to setup auto detection for fields located in the log.

Here it is my scrape_configs:

```
    scrape_configs:
  - job_name: system
    static_configs:
      - targets:
          - localhost
        labels:
          job: varlogs
          __path__: /var/log/sms-meeting/*.log
```

This is my winston logger config:

```
const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: "info",
  defaultMeta: { service: "myApp", env: process.env.NODE_ENV },
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.File({ filename: "logs/error.log", level: "error" }),
    new winston.transports.File({ filename: "logs/combined.log" }),
  ],
});
```

Comment: Are you sure you **need** conversion of json into labels on the promtail's side? AFAIK, grafana advises against it, in favor of converting then on-the-fly inside your queries , like `{filename="my-log.json"} | json`

Comment: You mean I should store my logs into another format in my .log files ? Sorry if this seems stupid, I'm very new into thos kind of ops stuff

Comment: No. Your log file seems to contain data in the json format. If it is, you don't need to parse it in the promtail. Simply pass it into loki as-is. And then, when querying data from loki you can parse json as I showed the previous comment.

Comment: Check this article: https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/get-started/labels/#optimal-loki-performance-with-parallelization

Comment: Thanks for the article. I didn't figure it out, how to require promtail to stop parsing the logs ? It seems to be the default way of working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a best practice, **you shouldn't setup auto detection of json fields during your log ingestion**. You want to ensure you primarily use static labels, sparingly use dynamic labels, and never use unbounded labels. Refer to the official [Loki Label Best Practices](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/get-started/labels/bp-labels/) for further information on each point.

You should instead leverage LogQL parsers to extract your json fields and make them available at query time. See the documentation for [LogQL parser expressions](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/query/log_queries/#parser-expression).

To give you an example from the public *Play* instance of Grafana:

**JSON Logs with no LogQL Parser** ([Open Demo](https://play.grafana.org/goto/lYO4aFWIg?orgId=1))
The only fields available are the ones applied during ingestion as *indexed* labels.
[image]

**JSON Logs WITH a LogQL json Parser** ([Open Demo](https://play.grafana.org/goto/RvcFaFZIg?orgId=1))
As you can see, all of the json fields are now available as fields within Grafana, and can be used in the remainder of your query as if they were part of the index.
[image]

---

It's very important that you are mindful of your [cardinality](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/get-started/labels/#cardinality) when choosing which labels to send with your logs during ingestion. In saying that, if there is something you really must extract from your log line during ingestion and apply as a label, you should refer to the [label pipeline stage](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/send-data/promtail/stages/labels/) in your scrape config.

Comment: Thanks, with your fully explained answer I finally understood what I did wrong. Just had to add | json in my query IN Grafana explorer. 

But, I didn't understood this part of you answer: you shouldn't setup auto detection of json fields during your log ingestion. What is auto detection ? This is like a configuration inside promtail to force labels ? Like both filename and job I had by default ?

Comment: @ebillis, yes that is exactly what "label auto detection" means in this context. Theoretically, promtail can convert every field of your JSON into label, but you shouldn't do it.

Comment: Okay this is very clear. Thanks have a nice day.